# drupal panel or regions?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, grid, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I want to make my Drupal 7 site look like exactly like 
www.io1.biz

what should I do?
the difference is that I want to add three views of latest content types instead of that three columns below the biggest image... and I want to change the pictures.
what should I do? should I user panels or customize drupal regions? It looks like simple.
if the answer is panels,my site has some ajax problems with panels,that I don't know how to fix this at the moment.[issue is [here](http://drupal.org/node/1863608) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52902/panels-ajax-problem) ]
and which theme should I use? the only thing is to add border-bottom to the h1 tags! I think....
is there any theme that I can make this subtheme simply with drag n drop??
thank you masters

Comment: by the way, theme should be rtl . thank you everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Zeropoint theme it have three regions option and copy paste the page.tpl.php and rename it to page--front.tpl.php and customize it to your requirement.

io1.biz website is very simple, you can easily make a copy of this site.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using regions. It's more flexible and maintainable.

And if these blocks are going to be present ONLY in the front page, it will be better to use a separate template for the front page `page--front.tpl.php`.